# JSP WebServet Annotation: URLPattern mapped to Method (GET,POST etc)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, annotations

Is there any way in creating a Servlet with the `@WebServlet` annotation to where I can map a urlpattern to a specific HTTP method (`doGet()`, `doPost()`)?  I would like to have a single Servlet with one URL mapped to the `doGet()` and another URL mapped to the `doPost()`. For Example:

/GetWidget => `WidgetServlet.doGet()`

/UpdateWidget => `WidgetServlet.doPost()`

/CreateWidget => `WidgetServlet.doPut()`

/DeleteWidget => `WidgetServlet.doDelete()`

Comment: Does not really make sense. Why not map it to `getWidget()` `updateWidget()` and so on? Anyway, look at JAX RS, where you annotate all methods with `@Path()` (but I would not use the doXxx() Methods!).

Comment: There are a couple of reasons. First I may have to add another pararmeter to the Widget.get() method (like user info for security purposes.  Also I will be using a Mapper class to be the interface between the source (a DB) and the Bean (a Widget).  I'm pretty sure you can't map URLs to the specific HTTP methods, but am just looking for confirmation.

Comment: You could use springMVC to achive this. Use the controller to map urls like @RequestMapping(value = "/CreateWidget", method = RequestMethod.PUT).